# Get all Methods with a given return type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is this code wrong? It's just not returning anything:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetMethodsOfReturnType(Type cls, Type ret)
{
   var methods = cls.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   var retMethods = methods.Where(m => m.ReturnType.IsSubclassOf(ret))
                           .Select(m => m.Name);
   return retMethods;
}
```

It's returning an empty enumerator.

*Note: I'm calling it on a ASP.NET MVC Controller looking for ActionResults*

```
GetMethodsOfReturnType(typeof(ProductsController), typeof(ActionResult));
```

Comment: Don't ActionResult methods need to be public in order to be callable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Others have pointed out fixes, but I'd like to suggest an alternative to `IsSubclassOf` as well as including public methods:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetMethodsOfReturnType(Type cls, Type ret)
{
   // Did you really mean to prohibit public methods? I assume not
   var methods = cls.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                BindingFlags.Public |
                                BindingFlags.Instance);
   var retMethods = methods.Where(m => m.ReturnType.IsAssignableFrom(ret))
                           .Select(m => m.Name);
   return retMethods;
}
```

With [`IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=VS.100).aspx), you don't need to have the extra "is the return type exactly the same as the desired type" test, and also it will work with interfaces.

Comment: Hard to know, but I would assume in production code the controller actions of interest would be only those that are public, perhaps filtered by only those not having the NonActionAttribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance

Where(m => ret == m.ReturnType || m.ReturnType.IsSubclassOf(ret))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two changes that could possibly make this work:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetMethodsOfReturnType(Type cls, Type ret)
{
   var methods = cls.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
   var retMethods = methods.Where(m => m.ReturnType.IsSubclassOf(ret) || m.ReturnType == ret)
                           .Select(m => m.Name);
   return retMethods;
}
```